# Combining if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a simple HTML5 & Javascript drag and drop game whereby the user should drag an image thats within a div for positioning into an empty div.

The drag and drop works correctly, and i've managed to code javascript to alert when the `#answer1` is dragged into the correct div, `#target`

However, when i duplicate the if statement, it alerts Correct but then also alerts incorrect, which i suspect is the second if statement running straight after.

Is there any way to sort of separate the statements so it only runs when an image is dragged, instead of running all the if statements?

```
function allowDrop(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));

  if($('#target1').find('#answer1').length == 1)
  {
    alert("CORRECT!");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!");
  }

  if($('#target2').find('#answer2').length == 1)
  {
    alert("CORRECT!");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!");
  }
}
```

JSFiddle For full webpage:

http://jsfiddle.net/hgDFU/1/

Comment: You could use `return` instead of alert, or alert what drop() will return. `return` will make the parser leave the function when it gets executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to only check the target that had an image dropped onto it. This makes it easier to add or remove targets to your game without having to change the code in `drop()`.

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));

    var targetnum = ev.target.id.replace("target", "");
    if($('#target' + targetnum).find('#answer' + targetnum).length == 1)
    {
        alert("CORRECT!");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is PERFECT! Thankyou so much. There is a couple of hitches, upon place the answer back into the designated starting area (for example if the user got it wrong) it alerts "Wrong" is there any way to avoid this happening? Or maybe reset the images position to original if the statement is incorrect?

Also, i get a message if the answers wrong within the alert box of "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogues" is this normal?

Comment: To stop it from alerting "Wrong", just take that alert out of the code. That would also be where you would put the code to reset the images. And yes, that message is completely normal.

Answer (score 2):

As Ghillied said in the comments, this would be better practice:

```
function drop(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));

   alert(checkDrop());
}

function checkDrop() {

     if($('#target1').find('#answer1').length == 1){
        return "CORRECT!";
     } 
     else if($('#target2').find('#answer2').length == 1) {
        return "CORRECT!";
     }
     else {
       return "Wrong!";
     }
}
```